# How to make a line chart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, charts, line

I've been trying to find a good tutorial to make a simple line chart in Flutter but I can't find it anywhere. My goal is to replicate the following chart:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRT27.jpg)

I just need to know how to make multiple colored lines in a single chart and how to put that informational container in the top right corner of the chart. Besides, the class will receive two integers, which will determinate where the orange dot (see image) will be in the chart (the problem is I don't know how to put a single isolated dot inside the chart). Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: If you are looking for a good tutorial check this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LB7B3zudivI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can simply do this with CustomPaint, where you will find loads of tutorials (getting a line chart in there should be obvious), the better approach is using an existing library for this. And there is the package called charts_flutter. If you familiarize with it, you can then simply add any other type of chart to your app and I guess it will look more professional than doing it on your own (at least if I would have to that).